# Replacing characters using R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with 1 column, Address. It has values like:

```
A <- structure(list(Address = structure(1:3, .Label = c("&2340 P St", 
 "&5656 N St", "456 B Street"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Address", 
 row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
A
##        Address
## 1   &2340 P St
## 2   &5656 N St
## 3 456 B Street
```

I need to clean data – to erase all characters (or replace with space) if there is “&”.
I am expecting this result in my 2.csv file:

```
##        Address
## 1 456 B Street
```

Here's the code:

```
 A <-read.csv("U:/161/1.csv", header=T,sep=",")
 B<-gsub("&", " ", A$ADDRESS1, ignore.case = TRUE)
 write.table(B, file = "U:/161/2.csv", sep = ","
 , col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")
```

It only removes “&”. How do I remove the rest of address?

Comment: What is the rest of the adress you want removed?

Comment: You shouldn't keep the first two entries? If you want to remove rows with `&` you can use `grep('&', A$Address)`

Comment: Ah that might be what the OP is after.

Comment: What if I want to replace everything starts with '&' to empty record. Should I use gsub?

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` or `grepl` to identify which rows contain `&` then exclude those rows

```
B <- droplevels(A[!grepl('&', A$Address), ,drop=FALSE])
B
##       Address
## 3 456 B Street
```

notice that I wrap the `[` call in `droplevels` to ensure that the unused levels (those with `&`) are dropped
also, as in this case the result would only be 1 line, I included `drop=FALSE` to keep `B` as a `data.frame`

To use `grep` (which returns the index) you would use `-`

```
B <- droplevels(A[-grep('&', A$Address), ,drop=FALSE])
B
```

Comment: `grep` or `grepl` will both work, with slightly different syntax. See my edit

Comment: You probably have a variable named `F`, using `drop=FALSE` should work